# Looking for home networking hardware and software advice

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, home-networking, bridge, powerline-networking

Note: I originally wrote this up in a [blog post](http://leggetter.posterous.com/home-networking-help).

I've recently moved home and I now need to go to the trouble of sorting out my home network yet again. We had Virgin broadband in Hertford but you can't get Virgin in the street we've moved to so I've had to go with O2 Broadband. Normally I prefer to use my own hardware, and previously used the DLink DIR-655 router which was great, but in this situation I am using the O2 Wireless Box III since I only have an old Netgear DG834PN Wireless G modem router and I'd rather be using Wireless N.

Anyway, the place we have moved into has only one phone point in the hallway, has the best TV point in one room and the best place to put the TV and other entertainment stuff in yet another room. So, networking the house up for Internet and TV is required. The diagram below shows the things that I'll have in my home network but there are three points where I'm not quite sure what hardware to us.

1. Wireless Access Point/Bridge, that
   acts only as a wireless to wire
   bridge and not an AP, that links up
   a Media Centre/PC and a couple of
   consoles to the network. I'm pretty
   much settled on us an Acer Aspire
   Revo R3600 as my media PC, probably
   with Ubuntu or Windows and XBMC
   installed.
2. Wireless Access
   Point/Bridge, that acts only as a
   wireless to wire bridge and not an
   AP, that links up a device that can
   decode and stream TV from a TV
   aerial across the network.
3. The
   device that is connected to 2). At
   the moment I'm considering a
   HDHomeRun by SiliconDust.

At the moment I'm considering either the TP LINK TL-WA701ND 150Mbps Wireless Lite N Access Point (very cheap at Amazon) or the Netgear 5 GHz Wireless-N HD Access Point/Bridge.

I'd love to get some insight into what you would do in my situation.

- What Wireless Access Point/Bridge
  should I put at points 1) and 2)?
- What device should I choose for point
  3) that can decode and stream a TV
  signal?
- Is the Acer Aspire Revo R3600
  a good choice?

[image: Network Map]

Answer (score 0):

Acer RL100 is pricey but awesome - the keyboard is very TRON - get one and a secondary TV tuner for it.

Have you considered using 100-200Mbs power-over-mains for the networking? This works very well, particularly in properties where WiFi is problematic.